# Regex for matching all but month/year in date

Tags: regex

I have a list of date lines like

```
05.22.2013
07.11.2015
12.31.2014
12.05.2015
06.11.2015
11.30.2015
```

I need a RegEx to filter all except 12.XX.2015.

Comment: Do you really need a regular expression? You could just split the dates on space and compare the list to the required date.

Comment: Wrong formatting. It's not separated by spaces. It needs to be a regex.

Comment: Are these date time strings validated already? You just need to match all but dates in December 2015? Have you tried at least some regex yet? You know, SO is not a "free code writing service", any efforts of yours are welcome here.

Comment: Have you tried any coding yet? SO posts that show you've tried something generally get more responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to verify the format, you could use

```
^(?!12.*2015).*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/bM8fF4/2

Comment: I think the outer parentheses are redundant here.

Comment: @stribizhev indeed they are, removed them

Comment: I would use a more precise `^(?!12\.\d{2}\.2015$)\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$`

Answer (score 0):

Since the other suggestion filters out any strings starting with `12` and containing `2015` anywhere further in the string, I think a more precise solution should be posted.

You can use a negative lookahead `(?!12\.\d{2}\.2015$)` anchored at the start of the pattern. It will fail a match (=the match won't be found) if the whole string matches the `<start_of_string>12.<digit><digit>.2015<end_of_string>` pattern. Note that the `.` must be escaped with a backslash (in some notations, it must be doubled) to match a literal period symbol. The `\d{2}` will match any date (and even more, but  in this case, all the date strings are pre-validated, so that is not an issue). The `$` at the end of the lookahead is very important since it means that the string should end with `2015`, no more text is allowed.

Use

```
^(?!12\.\d{2}\.2015$)\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fR1bW6/1)

*Regex explanation*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!12\.\d{2}\.2015$)` - the restrictive lookahead filtering out December 2015 dates
- `\d{2}` - exactly two digits
- `\.` - a literal period
- `\d{2}` - exactly two digits
- `\.` - a literal period
- `\d{4}` - exactly four digits
- `$` - end of string.

Note that in different notations, the backslash might need doubling.